# XSL - GML to json

Tags: sql-server, xml, xslt

I am working on a project that requires the transformation of an SQL geography type to a json array. My chosen method at this point is to select the SQL geography using AsGML (giving me a GML representation).

I am using xslt to transform this resulting GML into the json format that I need.

I am not an expert at xslt - and this is probably an easy issue.

The problem that I have now is that the return for the posList element has a trailing comma that I am unable to remove from the final result.

Thanks in advance for any assistance - example code follows:

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="MultiSurface">
<MultiGeometry>
<xsl:apply-templates />
</MultiGeometry>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Polygon">
<Polygon>
<xsl:apply-templates />
</Polygon>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Point">
<Point>
<xsl:apply-templates />
</Point>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="exterior">
{"ringtype":"exterior",
<xsl:apply-templates />
},
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="interior">
{"ringtype":"interior",
<xsl:apply-templates />
},
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="posList">
"coordinates":[
<xsl:call-template name="split">
<xsl:with-param name="str" select="normalize-space(.)" />
</xsl:call-template>
]
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="pos">
<coordinates>
<xsl:call-template name="split">
<xsl:with-param name="str" select="normalize-space(.)" />
</xsl:call-template>
</coordinates>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="split">
<xsl:param name="str" />
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="contains($str,'' '')">
<xsl:variable name="first">
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(substring-before($str,'' '')),''00.000000'')" />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="second">
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(substring-before(substring-after(concat($str,'' ''),'' ''),'' '')),''00.000000'')" />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="concat(''['',$first,'','',$second,''],'')" />
<xsl:call-template name="split">
<xsl:with-param name="str">
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after($str,'' ''),'' '')"/>
</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input example:

```
<Polygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
  <exterior>
    <LinearRing>
      <posList>32.230546755000034 -95.316506964999917 32.230542547000084 -95.316051441999946</posList>
    </LinearRing>
  </exterior>
</Polygon>
```

Output Example (note the trailing comma in the coordinates element)

```
<Polygon>
{"ringtype":"exterior",
"coordinates":[
[32.230547,-95.316507],[32.230543,-95.316051],[32.230536,-95.315358],
]
},
</Polygon>
```

Comment: Is the trailing space, or the trailing comma you are trying to remove?

Comment: Sorry - trailing comma in the coordinates array (I've edited the post)

Comment: rpmatt, the xslt code contains errors and won't parse. Please, edit the question and correct.

Comment: wow. XSL is such a verbose language. I knew that, of course, but I never really realised just how verbose it could be until I saw this. Sixty lines of unreadable XSL that could have been done in ten easily readable lines of virtually any other language.

Comment: by the way, if you're outputting JSON, why are you including the `<Polygon>` tag in the output?

Comment: Sorry - This was just (and actually still is) a work in progress - working off a previous method (so it's half/half) at this point.

Comment: Oh - and on the compile - it was that I cut and pasted it out of an SQL string assignment - so - double ticks instead of one - I'll remember that in further post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I have corrected your xslt (and there were *many* corrections) from one that wouldn't compile, into one that doesn't produce extraneous commas**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.opengis.net/gml" exclude-result-prefixes="x">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="x:MultiSurface">
        <MultiGeometry>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </MultiGeometry>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:Polygon">
        <Polygon>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </Polygon>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:Point">
        <Point>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </Point>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:exterior">
    <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::exterior">,</xsl:if>
    {"ringtype":"exterior",
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    }
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:interior">
    {"ringtype":"interior",
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    },
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:posList">
    "coordinates":[
        <xsl:call-template name="split">
            <xsl:with-param name="str" select="normalize-space(.)" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    ]
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:pos">
        <coordinates>
            <xsl:call-template name="split">
                <xsl:with-param name="str" select="normalize-space(.)" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </coordinates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="split">
        <xsl:param name="str" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($str,' ')">
                <xsl:variable name="first">
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(substring-before($str,' ')),'00.000000')" />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="second">
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(substring-before(substring-after(concat($str,' '),' '),' ')),'00.000000')" />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('[',$first,',',$second,']')" />

                <xsl:if test="substring-after(substring-after($str,' '),' ')">
                 <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:call-template name="split">
                        <xsl:with-param name="str">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after($str,' '),' ')"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Polygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <exterior>
        <LinearRing>
            <posList>32.230546755000034 -95.316506964999917 32.230542547000084 -95.316051441999946</posList>
        </LinearRing>
    </exterior>
</Polygon>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Polygon>
    {"ringtype":"exterior",

    "coordinates":[
        [32.230547,-95.316507], [32.230543,-95.316051]
    ]

    }
    </Polygon>
```

Comment: Thank you very much - It worked in my Visual Studio .NET CLR (except for the comma) - but like I said - I'm a novice. You are a livesaver!

Comment: What xml/xslt editor would you recommend - I currently just have visual studio and of course a couple of on-line ones?

Comment: @rpmatt, I have been using the Xselerator for more than 10 year and it is still the best (for me). Unfortunately, its author pulled it from sourceforge.net. Visual Studio provides a good XSLT IDE for XSLT 1.0. Another, very rich with capabilities and coverage IDE is that provided by oXygen -- its price for idividuals isn't high.

Comment: noting your use of  <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::exterior">,</xsl:if>. Is there a way from within the match "interior" block to see if the <Polygon> will be closing next? The reason for this is basically the same as the trailing comma in the question itself - if I have multiple interior/exterior elements - I get trailing commas. however, this (I think) is my last hurdle... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got it - thanks again for you help - i use  <xsl:template match="exterior">
    <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::exterior">,</xsl:if>
    {"ringtype":"exterior",
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    }
 <xsl:if test="following-sibling">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>